# Combining scale_y_sqrt() and limits drops first y-axis break

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to combine

- an y-axis sqrt scale and
- set y-axis limits.

The problem is, that `scale_y_sqrt( limits = c(0,10))` results in the y-axis losing the first break (0).

How can I rewrite this to get the desired result?

**R code** of minimum example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

N <- 10
test_data <- data.frame(
  idx  <- 1:N,
  vals <- runif( N, min = 0, max = 10)
)

grid.arrange(
  ggplot( test_data, aes(x = idx)) + 
    geom_line( aes(y = vals)) + 
    scale_y_continuous( limits = c(0,10)),
  ggplot( test_data, aes(x = idx)) + 
    geom_line( aes(y = vals)) + 
    scale_y_sqrt( limits = c(0,10)),
  ncol = 2
)
```

**plot output:**
[image: Plot output of above source]

- left plot has correct axis breaks, but without sqrt scale
- right plot has correct scaling, but misses the '0'-break

Comment: it's weird, but if you add `expand=c(0,0)` in your scale the zero reappears.

Comment: @baptiste: Thanks, I can confirm that. That however drops the space above 10 and below 0. The workaround from AEBilgrau's link does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue. See [the GitHub discussion](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/980) which also provide some workarounds.